# Хочу потренироваться в использовании Retrofit в android разработке, посоветуйте, пожалуйста, несколько сайтов с открытым api

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

Хочу потренироваться в использовании Retrofit в android разработке, посоветуйте, пожалуйста, несколько сайтов с открытым api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот довольно крупный [сборник](https://github.com/public-apis/public-apis) различных Api

Comment: Премного благодарен!)